# Looking to configure custom URL for myapps.Microsoft.com

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I am looking forward to figure out how to add a custom URL for the myapps.Microsoft.com portal. Just the way myapps.wholefoods.com is configured. I have seen similar threads but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add a custom URL for the "myapps.Microsoft.com" portal .
Customizations of this portal are on our roadmap.Please vote [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13790661-allow-more-customization-of-the-myapps-microsoft-c) on azure uservoice portal for this feature.

You could configure My Apps portal with customized link for your organization, [such as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/access-panel-collections#enable-the-latest-my-apps-features) :
https://myapps.microsoft.com/contoso.com